# Uses of Wrapped typeclass in Control.Lens

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I'm having a hard time reading the types in the [Control.Lens.Wrapped](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.13.2.1/docs/Control-Lens-Wrapped.html) module and I'm not finding much else written about it or the `newtype` library it is apparently based on.  In particular I am wondering what sorts of things I can do while remaining in the `newtype` wrapper.  For instance let's say I have two lists that are in a `Data.Monoid.Sum` wrapper.  Is there some way I can easily `++` the lists and get back a new value still in a `Sum` wrapper?  I would want a function that, monomorphically, looks something like this:

```
canIdoThis :: ([a] -> [a] -> [a]) -> Sum [a] -> Sum [a] -> Sum [a]
```

so that I could do something like

```
canIdoThis (++) (Sum [1,2]) (Sum [3,4])
```

and get `Sum [1,2,3,4]`.  (Of course, `canIdoThis` would also work on `Product [a]`, etc.)

Any other tips or just a general write up of all the goodness one could do with `Control.Lens.Wrapped` is appreciated very much.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't use `Wrapped`, but:

```
import Data.Coercible

canIdoThis :: ([a] -> [a] -> [a]) -> Sum [a] -> Sum [a] -> Sum [a]
canIdoThis = coerce
```

Are you sure these should be wrapped in `Sum`? No `instance Num [a]` by default.

Comment: Just using `Sum` as a random example of a `newtype` wrapper that has `Wrapped` instances.  Sometimes I have wrapped up things and I want to operate on what's wrapped inside.

Comment: `coerce (++) (Sum [1,2,3]) (Sum [4,5,6]) :: Sum [Int]` does not work in GHCi.

Comment: It doesn't know that the `[1,2,3]` is also `[Int]`, or that the (++) is supposed to concatenate `[Int]`s as opposed to, say, `[Sum Int]`s. `coerce ((++) :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]) (Sum [1,2,3] :: Sum [Int]) (Sum [4,5,6] :: Sum [Int]) :: Sum [Int]` works.